# LINQ to transform array [x0,y0, ..., xN, yN] into enumerable [p0, ..., pN]

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Is it possible to use LINQ to transform a flat array of doubles containing coordinate tuples (x, y),i.e. [x0,y0, ..., xN, yN] to an array of half the length containing the same coordinates wrapped in a `Point`-class, i.e. [p0, ..., pN]?

Preferably .NET 3.5, but also interrested in 4.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`.Batch`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/Batch.cs) from Jon Skeet's [morelinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/):

```
IEnumerable<Point> points = coordinates.Batch(2,pair => new Point(pair.ElementAt(0), pair.ElementAt(1)));
```

In all honestly, the simplest solution is probably using a method (here with `int`s):

```
public IEnumerable<Point> GetPoints(int[] coordinates)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.Length; i += 2)
    {
        yield return new Point(coordinates[i], coordinates[i + 1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the method based solution. looks better and much more readable.

Comment: Accepted because none of the LINQ solutions really produced clear code.

Answer (score 3):

```
double[] arr = { 1d, 2d, 3d, 4d, 5d, 6d };
var result = arr.Zip(arr.Skip(1), (x, y) => new Point(x, y))
                .Where((p, index) => index % 2 == 0);
```

EDIT: In this LINQ statement, the collection is looped through twice, which is not efficient. A better solution is using a `for` loop. And `Zip` is new in C# 4.0, an alternative is:

```
var result = arr.Select((n, index) => new Point(n, arr[index + 1]))
                .Where((p, index) => index % 2 == 0);
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I nede this for .NET 3.5, but I guess this does the job for 4.0. Not the most elegant query I've seen though - so maybe I'm better off with a plain old approach.

Comment: @larsm: I have added a solution for c# 3.5

Comment: Nice solution. Much simpler than mine :) +1

Comment: Your alternative produces an IndexOutOfRangeException - I've added amended code below as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This will just loop once and will work in 3.5

```
        int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3 };

        if (arr.Length % 2 != 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

        Point[] result = arr
                        .Where((p, index) => index % 2 == 0)
                            .Select((n, index) => new Point(n, arr[index * 2 + 1]))
                               .ToArray();
```

And here's another (possibly more "pure") option:

```
public static class Program
{

    public static IEnumerable<Point> ToPoints(this IEnumerable<int> flat)
    {
        int idx = 0;
        while(true)
        {
            int[] parts = flat.Skip(idx).Take(2).ToArray();
            if (parts.Length != 2)
                yield break;

            idx += 2;
            yield return new Point(parts[0], parts[1]);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7 };

        var x = arr.ToPoints().ToArray();

        return;
    }
```

}

Comment: I'm not quite sure why this question attracts such creative answers `:)`. If you insist on Linq, I think that relying on the array (`arr[...]`) is somewhat cheating (In a purist sort of way). You might as well use `Enumerable.Range(0, coordinates.Length / 2).Select(i => new Point(coordinates[i * 2], coordinates[i * 2 + 1]))`, but that is rather pointless, in my opinion - it has the same effect as my `for` loop.

Comment: the array is just a convenient IEnumerable.  And yes, it has the same effect as a for loop, but the question was indeed to do it in Linq ;)

Comment: I've just worked out what you really meant - just tried to implement it using IEnumerable instead of an array, lol.  Thanks for the insight!

Comment: not accurate. The array is an excellent `IEnumerable` - you get to use `arr[i]` which is potentially more efficient than `arr.ElementAt(i)`. Again, that can easily be corrected, but you don't have a "purely" functional solution anyway - you rely on external storage. In any case, you are right - the question is asking for linq. (oh, you're already there `:P`. I write too much)

Comment: Yes, I think we're agreeing :)

Answer (score 0):

Sure. I haven't compiled /run, so it may have typos, but the gist should be right.

```
var newArray = source.Aggregate(new List<double>, 
     (xCoords, next) => 
        {
           if(xCoords.length % 2 == 0) {
              xCoords.Add(next);
           }

           return xCoords;
        },
     xCoords => xCoords
     ).Zip(source.Aggregate(new List<double>, 
        (yCoords, next) => 
           {
              if(yCoords.length % 2 != 0) {
                 yCoords.Add(next);
              }

              return yCoords;
           },
        yCoords => yCoords
    , (x, y) => new Point(x, y)
    ).ToArray();
```